# Add url preview for a Flash

Tags: web, flash, thumbnails

I'm trying to build a free flash site for my website. I got a template and i uploaded it [here](http://team1635.site40.net/)

I haven't changed the pictures yet. If i want to upload my pictures (HIGH RES) it will take up a lot of space (and there are more than 600 pics, even if i want to convert them), even for my real website (team1635.org). So i was wondering if i can give a preview from my Flickr page in the swf file.

The xml code is:

```
<config
    folder="photos/"
    enable_fullscreen="true"
    drag_speed="2.4"    

    thumbnail_complete_fillup="true"
    thumbnail_random_scale="false"
    thumbnail_black_white="false"
    thumbnail_size="150"
    thumbnail_gap="1"

    photo_border_size="10"
    photo_border_color="#FFFFFF"

    close_button="true"
    previous_button="true"
    next_button="true"

    description="false"
    description_bg_color="#000000"
    description_bg_alpha="0.7"
    css_file="flashmo_210_style.css"
    tween_duration="0.6">
</config>

<photo>
    <thumbnail>s_photo_101.jpg</thumbnail>
    <filename>photo_101.jpg</filename>
</photo>

<photo>
    <thumbnail>s_photo_102.jpg</thumbnail>
    <filename>photo_102.jpg</filename>
</photo>

<photo>
    <thumbnail>s_photo_103.jpg</thumbnail>
    <filename>photo_103.jpg</filename>
</photo>

<photo>
    <thumbnail>s_photo_104.jpg</thumbnail>
    <filename>photo_104.jpg</filename>
</photo>

<photo>
    <thumbnail>s_photo_105.jpg</thumbnail>
    <filename>photo_105.jpg</filename>
</photo>

<photo>
    <thumbnail>s_photo_106.jpg</thumbnail>
    <filename>photo_106.jpg</filename>
</photo>

<photo>
    <thumbnail>s_photo_107.jpg</thumbnail>
    <filename>photo_107.jpg</filename>
</photo>

<photo>
    <thumbnail>s_photo_108.jpg</thumbnail>
    <filename>photo_108.jpg</filename>
</photo>

<photo>
    <thumbnail>s_photo_109.jpg</thumbnail>
    <filename>photo_109.jpg</filename>
</photo>

<photo>
    <thumbnail>s_photo_110.jpg</thumbnail>
    <filename>photo_110.jpg</filename>
</photo>
```

So is there any way to add  [this picture](http://www.flickr.com/photos/nakzz/12624607854/)
There without downloading the whole picture.

I'm new to programing so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think https://www.flickr.com/services/api/ will help you.

Also, the below might help you too ;-)

[image]